# How do I update JSON file using PowerShell (Patch Method)

Tags: json, powershell, updates

I have a json file like below, and I want to update values using a PowerShell script

```
{
  "rows": [{
    "id": 111,
    "name": "xrx",
    "serial": "A123456",
    "model": {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "wlw"
    },
    "model_number": "2323",
    "status_label": {
      "id": 22,
      "name": "out"
    }  
    }]
}
```

I want to edit the status label id and name (status_label -> id & name). Is there any way I can edit it with Powershell?

Comment: There's a comma missing after `"model_number": "2323"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use ConvertFrom-Json and ConvertTo-Json functions.

```
$Json = Get-Content C:\Temp\json.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$Json.rows.status_label.id = "newID"
$Json.rows.status_label.name = "newName"
$Json | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File C:\Temp\newJson.json
```

When you use ConvertFrom-Json you will get a PowerShell object which you can manipulate as every other object. Then you can convert the object back into Json string and overwrite the old file or save it as a new one.

Comment: the form in json was changed, and because of that i can't change another time. any solutions?
the status_label look like this after running this code: "status_label": "@{id=999; name=nn}"

Comment: How did the JSON change? If you check what $Json.rows.status_label  is (with | Get-Member for example) you'll see that it's an object with 2 properties. Id and name. You have to dig deeper :)

Comment: @sam ConvertTo-Json has a -Depth flag, if the change was that the json got shallower it might help to set it higher